# How to create a UIImageView in Swift Playgrounds for iPad?

Tags: swift, image, uiimageview

I was wondering how to create a UIImageView and set it’s image property and show it on the live view. This is Swift Playgrounds for iPad so there is no storyboards. I can’t add in a UIImageView unless I code it. How do I create a UIImageView in Swift Playgrounds for iPad?

Answer (score 0):

```
let image = UIImage(named: “photo.png”)
let imageView = UIImageView()
imageView.image = image
view.addSubview(imageView)
imageView.Frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: int, height: int)
```

This creates a custom frame. To have the frame match the image use `imageView.image = UIImage(named: image)` This is based of of rmaddy’s comment below

Comment: Why not use `let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)` ?

Comment: There's a big difference. Your code creates an image with a zero frame. My suggestion creates the image view the same size as the image.

Comment: Hmm. Yeah I see I forgot to add that